# What mappings is Automapper applying?

Tags: automapper

I have a problem where a mapping works when applied as the child of one object but not another and I am clueless how to debug this.

I map a complex object such as:

ParentType1
-> ChildType1
-> GrandchildType1
PropertyA

which is transformed to

ParentType2
-> ChildType2
-> GrandchildType2
PropertyB

PropertyB is populated

through a tonne of mapping files (I inherited this code) and works fine.

I have another object

ParentType3
-> ChildType3
-> GrandchildType1
PropertyA

which I am trying to map to another object

ParentType4
-> ChildType4
-> GrandchildType2
PropertyB

PropertyB is empty

which doesn't work. In both cases GrandchildType1 is being converted to GrandchildType2. The problem is the transform for Grandchild1 to GrandChild2 is not being applied in the second scenario. How can I tell which mappings are being applied in the first case so I can compare with the second. The application has thousands of lines of code so I am not about to ditch automapper. If I post the mappings here it will take up hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: It's hard to tell without some concrete code. How are your mappings configured? We don't need all of them, just enough to diagnose.

Comment: @Lucian, I have checked the execution plans and done a diff and I can see no appreciable difference between them other than variable names

Comment: You have some plain C# code that runs and transforms an input to an output. No magic here. So take the time to understand why. If it seems difficult, you need to make the problem smaller until you see it.